# Do Microservices inter communicate using API Calls or just only using Message Brokers?

Tags: c#, .net, spring-boot, kubernetes, microservices

I Developed two microservices and I integrated RabbitMQ also as a Message Broker. My concern is, Does microservice architecture allows inter-communication using direct API Calls or it totally depend on
Message Broker for intercommunication?

As a example :- Immediate important business scenarios like, Customer place a order, this should contain API Calls to customerAPI to orderAPI rather than depending on Message Broker which consider as Asynchronous operations.

```
    [Route("CallOrder")]
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Product>> CallOrder()
    {
        logger.LogInformation("Call product controller from customer and get products");
        return  await httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<IEnumerable<Product>>("http://shoppingapi-service/Product");
    }
```

I just want to clarify is According to Microservice Architecture, Do we actually use API Calls to communicate one microservice to another or we totally depend on Message brokers. Or we use both

I tried Both ways such as API Calls and Message Broker for the communication, AS I believe it depends on the business scenario it is a urgent task, I went with API Calls. If its not I go with Message broker. Producer - Consumer  way.

Comment: You could use API calls for direct communication and message brokers for integration events. Plus, using gRPC between microservices will yield much better performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do we actually use API Calls to communicate one microservice to another or we totally depend on Message brokers. Or we use both

In microservice architecture you are not limited to asynchronous style of communication  (see [Pattern: Messaging @microservices.io](https://microservices.io/patterns/communication-style/messaging.html)), in some cases synchronous RPS/RPI can be used too ([Pattern: Remote Procedure Invocation (RPI) @microservices.io](https://microservices.io/patterns/communication-style/rpi.html)) though due to the nature of the microservice architecture and problems which you want to solve with it usually it heavily favors asynchronous options due to it's ability to provide better decoupling between services and scalability.

> Immediate important business scenarios like, Customer place a order, this should contain API Calls to customerAPI to orderAPI rather than depending on Message Broker which consider as Asynchronous operations.

TBH I will challenge your conclusion here. While placing order is definitely a "important" business scenario it does not mean that it can't be handled in asynchronous manner. Apart from using the asynchronous communication channel in synchronous manner there are other options - like propagate the async communication to UI (via websockets) or use local copy/"cache" of other services data in the service handling order placement (and maintain that copy by using async communication to keep it updated). This is actually quite common scenario in microservice architecture when data is duplicated (in readonly manner) across multiple services (for example [Pattern: Command-side replica](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/command-side-replica.html)).

Answer (score 0):

While there's no one way to do things, it's best to pick one and stick to it.

There are ways to have blocking request-response style communication over message brokers too. For an example, see MassTransit's RequestClient: https://masstransit.io/documentation/concepts/requests